# how to configure redis, hsqldb,zookeeper, multiple admin in spring xd

Tags: spring-xd

I want to create a distributed cluster in spring xd.
I am able to create a cluster with single admin, one zookeeper, one instance of redis and hsqldb.
But when i'm trying to do that with multiple instance of zookeeper , hsqldb, redis ,i'm not able to configure it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have a single instance of zookeeper, hsqldb and redis. All xd-admins should be configured to connect to the same instance of each of these services and so should the xd-containers be.

Comment: If the machine with zookeeper fails, it'll be a SPOF for my system. That's why i want multiple zookeeper. Moreover i'm not able to configure Rabbit mq correctly.

Comment: For Zookeeper you would set up an ensemble that would provide the fault tolerance and then your XD nodes would all connect to the same ZK ensemble. See - http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup. Maybe start a new question for your issue with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Like Thomas has mentioned, the idea is that you have your (multiple) instances of admin and containers deployed, and all connect to the same zk,redis, hsqldb & rabbitmq.

Why do you want to start multiple instances of these applications?

Zookeeper provides the topology of the cluster and manages deployments. Also, it makes sure to note when nodes go up and down - avoiding single point of failures when you have many xd-admin instances (one is leader and the others replicate, they will become leader if the current one fails).

Or are you talking about making those instance parallel to avoid a SPOF? In that case, you should try to dedicate an entire VM for each of those applications.

Comment: If the machine with zookeeper fails, it'll be a SPOF for my system.
That's why i want multiple zookeeper.
Moreover i'm not able to configure Rabbit mq correctly.